# SUM of metric for normalized logical hierarchy

Tags: sql, recursion, teradata

Suppose there's a following table Table1, describing parent-child relationship and metric:

```
Parent | Child | Metric (of a child)
------------------------------------
name0 | name1 | a  
name0 | name2 | b  
name1 | name3 | c  
name2 | name4 | d  
name2 | name5 | e  
name3 | name6 | f
```

Characteristics:
1) Child always has 1 and only 1 parent;
2) Parent can have multiple children (name2 has name4 and name5 as children);
3) Number of levels in this "hierarchy" and number of children for any given parent are arbitrary and do not depend on each other;

I need SQL request that will return result set with each name and a sum of metric  **of all its descendants down to the bottom level plus itself**, so for this example table the result would be (look carefully at **name1**):

```
Name | Metric
------------------
name1 | a + c + f  
name2 | b + d + e  
name3 | c + f  
name4 | d  
name5 | e  
name6 | f
```

(name0 is irrelevant and can be excluded).

It should be ANSI or Teradata SQL.

I got as far as a recursive query that can return a SUM (metric) of all descendants of a given name:

```
WITH RECURSIVE temp_table (Child, metric) AS
(  
   SELECT root.Child, root.metric  
   FROM table1 root  
   WHERE root.Child = 'name1'  
   UNION ALL  
   SELECT indirect.Child, indirect.metric  
   FROM temp_table direct, table1 indirect  
   WHERE direct.Child = indirect.Parent
)  
SELECT SUM(metric) FROM temp_table;
```

Is there a way to turn this query into a function that takes name as an argument and returns this sum, so it can be called like this?

```
SELECT Sum_Of_Descendants (Child) FROM Table1;
```

Any suggestions about how to approach this from a different angle would be appreciated as well, because even if the above way is implementable, it will be of poor performance - there would be a lot of iterations of reading metrics (value f would be read 3 times in this example). Ideally, the query should read a metric of each name only once.

Comment: Have you considered a recursive view definition where you specify the child when querying it?

Comment: @RobPaller: I think this is a good idea; post it as an answer so I can vote it up!

Comment: How would that be an advantage over recursive query? I would still have to hard-code the initial 'root' name in the view definition, right?

Comment: Can you post the recursive query you have right now? It may be as simple as adding a where clause.

Comment: can you use another tool for the recursive sum?  Teradata is more of a warehouse tool than a relational data management tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** This answer applies to SQL Server 2005 and above where Common Table Expressions are supported. I did not pay attention to the `teradata` tag when I first answered the question. Hopefully, this answer is still relevant as the syntax appears to be almost the same.

This can be achieved in SQL Server by expanding the hierarchy for each level as

```
with recursive temp_table (RootValue, Child, Metric)
as 
(select
    root.Child, root.Child, root.Metric
from table1 root
union all
select
    direct.RootValue, indirect.Child, indirect.Metric
from temp_table direct join table1 indirect on indirect.Parent = direct.Child
)
select
    RootValue, SUM(Metric)
from temp_table
group by RootValue;
```

The (Common Table Expression) CTE definition has a RootValue column in addition to Child and Metric.
The CTE recursively associates Child & Metric values for a given RootValue.

Given this CTE, the desired output is just a matter of aggregating on the RootValue column.

Comment: Thanks. Took me some time to figure out how it works - all examples I saw had hard-coded initial value, so I assumed it's a must for recursion. The principal is explained well here - http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html